# How to Decode Bitfield offset in C++

Tags: c++

I was trying the get the bitfield offset from the struct.

```
struct Example{
    int a: 3;
    int b: 1;
    int c: 4;
};
```

I'm trying to get bitfield offset
expect result will be

```
a offset = 0, //0-2
b offset = 3, //3
c offset = 4  //4-7
```

Comment: The offsets depend on the implementation.

Comment: You can't do that. Why do you feel that you need to?

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question. If it depends on the implementation, then cite the part of the language specification that says so. If it cannot be done, then the answer is that it cannot be done. In either case, the answer can include a workaround.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? The idea of using bitfields is so that you don't need to know the offsets and masks, as you would when doing the packing yourself.

Comment: Do you ask about C or C++? Don't tag both language except you specifically ask about differences, similarities and compatibility between this 2 languages.

Comment: @WeatherVane No. This can be very useful for special function registers, such as port registers, where you may want to access individual bits sometimes and the whole register in other times.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 how would that work for port registers when the allocation of bitfields is [implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76180398/how-to-decode-bitfield-offset-in-c?noredirect=1#comment134345625_76180597)? Anyway, the device's header file definitions will give the information of bit positions.

Comment: @WeatherVane That is exactly the point. The question is about how to know which order the implementation uses. Because with this knowledge you can solve this problem. And just because it is implementation-defined does not mean useless, sometimes you know the implementation and can use it. For example the standard library / headers for PIC microcontroller uses bitfields to access individual bits of SFRs (special function registers).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 but the header file will give the offsets anyway (bit position). As given the question is a bit like reverse-engineering.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand what you are saying or you don't understand me. Anyway, point is: It is a very useful thing to know, it is used in the real world, can avoid many problems and therefore isn't a XY problem.

Comment: The alternative to fiddling with bit fields is: Storing integrals of well defined size (e.g. `std::uint8_t`) and isolate bit groups by bit operators (`&`, `|`, `<<`, `>>` etc.)

Comment: fwiw, there is [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof), but "Particularly, if member is a static data member, a bit-field, or a member function, the behavior is undefined.". Considering that `offsetof` already requires compiler magic to be implemented I doubt that there is a portable way for bit-fields.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 what I meant is that suppose the bitfield `struct` represents an ADC control register. The header will contain say `#define ADCCON_IEF 3` which identifies the bit. It's already done without needing to reverse-engineer the bitfield struct.

Comment: @WeatherVane Real world example, the header, provided from the manufacturer of the µC and compiler (microchip XC8 compiler for PIC16F1508), contains: `typedef union { struct { unsigned ANSC0 :1; unsigned ANSC1 :1; unsigned ANSC2 :1; unsigned ANSC3 :1; unsigned :2; unsigned ANSC6 :1; unsigned ANSC7 :1; }; struct { unsigned ANSELC :8; }; } ANSELCbits_t;` to access individual bits, and it is much easier to use than using a combination of `>>`,`<<`,`&`,`|`,`~` -> Therefore not a XY problem.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 so, what does OP need the bit offsets for? I do understand the use of the bitfield `struct`, but not what you are saying about reverse-engineering the positions, when you rule out the use of those bit operators.

Comment: @WeatherVane No reverse-engineering. I think you don't understand the problem. I can be very useful to know how the compiler fills a bitfield, in order to create a bitfield that matches the hardware, i questioned the same many times, since it would be very useful for embedded systems, i guess the C standard could include some optional macros, that are set by the compiler when the compiler follows a specific rule, but sadly the C standard doesn't contain that AFAIK.

Comment: If you need definitions that are not in the header, you can make them yourself. For example if you need to know the bit position of the second member, you can `#define ANSC1_BIT 1`, because it's a known fact about the hardware, and no less portable than the bitfield `struct`.

Answer (score 3):

Bitfields exist in the language precisely so that you do not have to care about bit offsets, and also, so that the compiler is free to move things around so as to optimize things as it sees fit. For example, if you have the following:

```
struct Example
{
    int a: 3;
    int b: 7;
    int c: 4;
};
```

The compiler may choose to group `a` and `c` in one byte-sized field and leave `b` alone in another byte of its own.

I do not know of any way to discover the offsets at which the compiler decided to store the bit fields, and my understanding of the language is such that I very highly doubt that there exists a way to discover this information.

If you must care about bit offsets, then you do not want to use bitfields; what you want within your struct is a field of type `unsigned int` (or other suitable type) in which you store the bits yourself, at offsets that you have pre-determined yourself.

If your `struct` contains nothing but bit-fields, then you do not need the struct at all, you can just replace the entire struct with an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Backing up my claim: C++20 11.4.10 "[...] Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined. [...]".

Comment: Knowing the order is very helpful, for example when you have a µC and a port. You could use a `union` of a `uint8_t` and a bitfield, the bitfield is used to access individual IOs, and the `uint8_t` is used to access the port. The standard library for PIC controllers does that, but they know their compiler and the order they use.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Your approach with the `union` sounds like [type punning](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-pun), and this is something else which is not standard conform in C++ (though AFAIK it's still allowed in C).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I don't know about C++ (The OP should really decide on C or C++). In C, a `uint8_t` is defined as having no padding, it must be the same as a `unsigned char` where it exist. You can read any accessable data with a `unsigned char` without worrying about type punning. And as said, it is done in the real world, and it works.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 OP says C++ in the title, and then seems to have the usual confusion that C would be just the same, because C++ is a superset, but it isnt. I removed the C tag (don't think it affects this answer)